# "the execution of" vs "execution of"

Tags: grammaticality

Please, have a look at the following sentences:

> Executing agency (also referred to as "executing entity") shall mean the entity responsible for execution of UN-Women programme activities as defined in regulation 27.2.
>
> The funds generated through the round tables should be allocated directly to UNDP, or to the United Nations and specialized agencies, or to the beneficiary Governments responsible for execution of these projects, in order to reduce the number of intermediaries and shorten time-lags.
>
> The Executive Director of UNEP shall be responsible for the execution of the functions of UNEP under this MOU.
>
> Judges responsible for the execution of sentences must be appointed; meanwhile, criminal judges must perform this function.
>
> The manufacturer shall be responsible for the execution of the approved plan of remedial measures.

Could you please explain why the zero article is used in the first two sentences before the word *execution*, while in the other three sentences there is the definite article before the same word?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may find better answers is ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: This looks very similar to a glossary. It is defining terms. Glossaries and definitions don't have to use perfect grammar the way prose does.

Comment: So which option is grammatically correct: "the execution of" or "execution of"?

Comment: @giga2712 "correct" in what context? That said, where an uncountable noun has a defining modifier, it is common (but not compulsory) to add a determiner.

Comment: @Greybeard Sorry, I can't provide further context since I found those sentences on Reverso Context. I am myself trying to assume what lies behind these sentences and why the definite articles is used or not used. I just thought that it would be easier for native speakers to assume the context than it is for me. Let me guess.

In the first sentence there is no article because "UN-Women programme activities" are not specifically defined, limited set of activities. They can include a lot of activities that fall under the same purpose (related to UN-Women organisation).

Comment: @Greybeard In the second sentence, there is no article because we are not referring to a specific activity of executing a project. If we were talking about of a specific process of execution carried out by one of "the beneficiary governments", we would use the definite article.

In the third sentence. we are talking about specific set of functions set out somewhere, that's why the word "execution" need the definite article.

Comment: @Greybeard In the fourth sentence we use the definite article because there are several things that can be done with respect to sentences, and we are talking about "execution" of sentences rather than, for instance, "rendering" sentences.

In the fifth sentence we are talking about execution of a specific plan defined in some document. Bacause we specifically know what we are executing, we should use the definite article.

Comment: CJ Dennis explained why the expected (but not mandatory) determiners are missing in your example - it is not "normal prose". See his post above. My explanation addressed the use of determiners in general, i.e. normal prose. As I read through your example, there are several determiners thta would be there, were the example not as CJ Dennis describes. In short, your example is a poor example of how determiners are used with uncountable and countable nouns.

Comment: @Greybeard "there are several determiners thta would be there, were the example not as CJ Dennis describes". Could you say which example are you referring to? There are 5 sentences.

Also, could you please demonstrate what you are saying on the sentences that I have given? It is a bit difficult to understand your explanation. Which determiners? Where should they be were it "normal prose"?